# Why is parent form invalid when all fields and forms inside it are valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have markup like this

```
form
  input
  input
  ngForm
    input
  submit
```

the input inside of the `ngForm` has an `ng-required` attribute with value set to false. The scope inspector confirms this and the DOM confirms this by showing that it does not have the `required` attribute.

The `ngForm` is valid and has class `ng-valid`. The input inside of it is valid and has class `ng-valid`. This is also true for all other inputs in the parent form.

For some reason though the parent form is invalid and has class `ng-invalid` and `ng-invalid-required`.

**Why, what could be causing this and how can I fix it?**

---

If I do `$('.ng-invalid')` in the console, the only result is the parent form. This confirms for me that no other field on the page is invalid.

The form controller's $error object looks like

```
{
  required: [
    {
      $error: {
        required: true
      },
      $invalid: true,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The way it is nested is a bit concerning. But I can't confirm that it is a problem.

---

If I enter a single character into the input the form remains invalid. But if I insert a *second* character into the input then the form turns valid! What!?

Comment: can you create a plunker to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: no, I can't duplicate the problem with simple markup. something more complex is going on.

Comment: Without a demo you wont find much help here.

Comment: Granted it is not an easy problem. Suggestions on what else could be a factor would be helpful.

Comment: Without a demo of your code, it's hard to offer much help. Other examples of ngForm seem to work well: http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/FNDjS/1/

Comment: Is it normal for the `$error` object to be nested the way I have shown?

Comment: this is how lost i am: http://plnkr.co/eZvnE4J7gdUZbPMaPPmc
can you tweak it to be, even a little, more like your situation?

Comment: @j.wittwer http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZXB722BZVIMLgIyqDXb this one is my work in progress but it does not present the defect.